# Find the mismatch columns from two tables with same structure

Tags: db2

I have two tables with same structure. I have to find the mismatch columns in both the tables based on id and year combination. Below is the table structure:
[image]

**id and year is primary key in both the tables.**

============================================================
Create table and insert script for table1:

```sql
create table table1 (id int, year int, name varchar(50), stat varchar(50), PRIMARY KEY (id,year));

insert into table1 values (1,2021,'Aman','L');
insert into table1 values (2,2021,'Ankit','H');
insert into table1 values (3,2021,'Rahul','G');
insert into table1 values (4,2021,'Gagan','L');
```

============================================================
Create table and insert script for table2:

```sql
create table table2 (id int, year int, name varchar(50), stat varchar(50), PRIMARY KEY (id,year));

insert into table2 values (1,2020,'Aman','H');
insert into table2 values (2,2020,'Anuj','M');
insert into table2 values (3,2020,'Rahul','G')
insert into table2 values (4,2020,'Abhi','L')
```

============================================================

**Expected Output:**

for example, id = 1 and year = 2021 from 1st table when compared with id = 1 and year = 2020 (table1 year -1) from table2 should return that stat is different.

id = 2 and year = 2021 from table1 when compared with id = 2 and year = 2020 from table2 should return that name and stat is different.

I need to compare the year-1 from table2 with year column of table1.

Can anyone help me with sql or DB2 query or procedure, how can I do that.

Comment: Provide sample data as formatted textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Provide desired output for this data.

Comment: @Akina Mentioned create and insert statements in the question.

Comment: Well, but where is the desired output? complete, in formattred table form?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a simple join

```
select * 
from table1 t1
     join table2 t2 
       on t1.id = t2.id
          and t1.year = t2.year + 1
where t1.stat <> t2.stat
      or t1.name <> t2.name --if you want this?
```